# Script of trajectory without itween

Tags: transformation

I use itween for trajectories of car.
I do not want to use him anymore because I find him very heavy.( more 100 cars in my scène)
I found scripts but all one a variable speed to turn around points.
It is always necessary to find the good compromise in the speed of the car and the rotation speed so that the car does not turn non-stop around a point
It is not easy with a car which goes to 90 kmh and a distance of point of 5 m.
I did not arrive this day and in spite of several tried scripts there.
[image]

I look for a script where we give the speed, the path.

Thank you

Comment: The rotations are always jerky and not fluid and regular